# PHP GET not working

Tags: php, get

Im trying to get the taskid variable from the url:

Long story short the database never updated trying to echo $tasked is blank and im not sure why.

I have looked over all of the suggestions and many different websites I do not see what i'm missing

http://domain.com/ubxtask/addnote.php?taskid=163994

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Add Note to Task</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
<textarea name="notetoadd" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dbusr";
$password = "dbpass";
$dbname = "db";

$notetoadd = $_POST['notetoadd'];

if (isset($_GET["taskid"])) {
//$taskid = $_GET['taskid'];
echo $_GET["taskid"];
//echo $taskid;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO tasknotestbl (tasknum, tasknote)
VALUES ('$taskid', '$notetoadd')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: http://domain.com/task/tasklist.php');
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: The form hasn't the taskid field...

Comment: And the form has no `action` set action to `action="addnote.php"`

Comment: Ok I tried both neither worked, I am using shellinbox to write the code and sometimes copy and paste inputs 'invisible' characters that  I cannot see unless using putty, found that out yesterday after a couple hours of trouble shooting a very simple problem, I will check it later today and if still not working will come back

Comment: I hate all the downvotes I get on this site, wish you would tell me why its a bad question

Comment: Ok figured it out, the reason I was not seeing the 'taskid' was because it was not being set until I hit submit, @Philipp answer would have been the second problem I would have run into, by moving the 'if (isset($_GET["taskid"])) {' out of the 'if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {' It works as expected, perhaps while you kind people were downvoting you might have picked up on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the task id to your forms action, or it would be lost, if you submit the form

```
<form action="addnote.php?taskid=<?php echo $_GET['taskid']; ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden field to form with taskid and use post method:

```
<?php   
if (empty($_GET['taskid'])) {
    $taskid = '1';
}else{
    $taskid = (int)$_GET['taskid'];
}

// your code submit code and
if (isset($_POST["taskid"])) {
echo $_POST["taskid"];
}

echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <p><textarea name="notetoadd" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="taskid" value="'.$taskid.'" placeholder="taskID">    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>';
?>
```